# Magnitude of force and point of application to keep semi-cylindrical gate in a fluid at equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

While working on a problem set I came across this question.

The figure shows a semi-cylindrical massless gate of width R pivoted at the point O holding a stationary liquid of density $\rho$. A horizontal force F is applied at its lowest position to keep it stationary. The magnitude of the force is ?
[image]

**My Attempt:**
Well we could conclude right off the bat that all pressure forces due to the liquid inside act perpendicular to the curved surface of the cylinder and end up passing through the pivot causing the net torque of pressure forces of the fluid to be **zero**.

While this cleared the entire story of balancing torque, we just need to balance horizontal forces, I think. Though here comes the vague bit of the question as well as my doubt.

*1. Is the pivot providing all necessary horizontal force to balance the effect of horizontal components of the forces on the curved surface of the cylinder ?*

To do so I worked out resultant of the horizontal forces on the curved surface to be equal to $\rho$*g*$R^3$ which should be somehow balanced by forces towards the left. In this case if I work under the assumption that the pivot provides exactly this force,

*2. Would the force F would no more be required?*

Alternatively, somehow the pivot provides no force horizontal force at all and is still able to function as a pivot (which I think is practically impossible discarding this case totally), the force F will come into action but it should still be applied exactly at the pivot right for torque to be balanced.

*3. It really isn't possible for the liquid to undergo any adjustment internally to be able to balance the force F and torque due to it if it's being applied anywhere else other than the pivot O right ?*

I reached out to my teacher and was told that the force due to the pivot existing cannot be worked out but my above analysis contradicts his claim. Please correct wherever I have gone wrong and answer me doubts 1,2,3 while also giving a final verdict as to what force F should be under what assumptions. I would appreciate if you shed light onto any new interesting points possible in this arrangement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly conclude that the liquid provides no torque about $O$, and neither can the pivot, so $F$ must be zero. Otherwise, it would cause a net torque. This answers your second question. The fluid isn't able to apply a torque and balance a non-zero $F$ applied at a point other than $O$: this answers your third question.

Static equilibrium requires the forces balance as well, so
$$\vec F_\text{pivot} = -\vec F_\text{liquid} $$
so the answer to your first question is yes.

Your teacher's claim that the pivot's force can't be calculated is a strange one. I suspect he is either wrong or means something else.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll get back to my teacher with this updated knowledge. Also he says "Yes torque will be zero,as all force vectors will pass through pivot only... there is unbalanced horizontal force on gate, but what reaction force pivot provides can't be worked out..."

Comment: @mewtonscat No problem. Clearly if there were a force imbalance, the gate would move. The pivot's force provides the balance and can be calculated since the liquid's force on the gate can be calculated.